# Imprimir ReportViewer si vista previa

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Tengo un código que me imprime un reporte de report viewer directamente a la impresora en ambiente de desarrollo me funciona pero cuando instalo en la maquina del cliente no me sirve los demás reportes que los muestro por pantalla me funcionan bien cuando instalo, he instalado todo en la maquina del cliente y todos los reportes generados para mostrar por pantalla me los muestra bien.

El código es el siguiente:

```
LocalReport rdlc = new LocalReport();
 rdlc.ReportPath = @"..\..\Reportes\Ventas\Facturas.rdlc";
 rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DsEncabezado", encabezado));
rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DsEncabezadoSede", encabezadoSede));
rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DsEncabezadoEmpresa", encabezadoEmpresa));
rdlc.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DsDetallesFactura", detalles));

                Impresion imp = new Impresion();
                imp.Imprime(rdlc);



   `
```

Comment: Y cuál es la respuesta? Qué muestra el sistema? Cuál es el error? Cuál es el resultado?

Comment: El error es e ha producido un error durante el procesamiento local de informes

Comment: Cual es el codigo del metodo Imprime() ? defines alli dentro un try..catch para obtener el mensaje del problema? que pasa si este reporte tambien lo visualizas, en ese caso funciona correctamente? si algun otro reporte qe visualizas y funciona lo envias a impresion directo, funciona o tambien falla, esto lo pregunto para validar que sea algo del reporte o de la funcionalidad de impresion directa